# Prolog truth set

Tags: prolog

A Boolean expression is of the form – in Prolog List

`[and, a, b, c, d]` or `[and, [or, b, c], [not, a], [and, c, d]]` – or any combination thereof – a,b,c,d are propositions.

Truth set is given in the form – in Prolog List

`[[a, t], [b, f], [c, t], [d, t]]` where a is true, b is false, c is true and d is true.

How can I write a Prolog predicate evalb which will takes in a Boolean expression as described above, and a truth set as described above, and binds the value of the evaluated Boolean expression to the last parameter.

Comment: You need to attempt a solution and post your attempt along with your question to get an answer.

Comment: Maybe you find [this](http://barrywatson.se/cl/cl_propositional_logic.html) as a good start for your implementation.